# Same LHS, different RHS in Haskell

Tags: haskell

The exercise I need to solve is this:

*Write a filter function for Foldable types using foldMap.*

```
filterF 
    :: ( Applicative f
       , Foldable t
       , Monoid (f a)
       ) 
    => (a->Bool) -> t a -> f a
filterF=undefined
```

*The function should return `True` for all of the following tests:*

```
unit_testFilterF1 = filterF Data.Char.isUpper "aNA aRe mEre" == "NARE"
unit_testFilterF1 = filterF Data.Char.isUpper "aNA aRe mEre" == First (Just 'N')
unit_testFilterF1 = filterF Data.Char.isUpper "aNA aRe mEre" == Min 'A'
unit_testFilterF1 = filterF Data.Char.isUpper "aNA aRe mEre" == Max 'R'
unit_testFilterF1 = filterF Data.Char.isUpper "aNA aRe mEre" == Last (Just 'E')
```

Using the hints our teacher gave us, I wrote this solution:

```
filterF 
    :: ( Applicative f
       , Foldable t
       , Monoid (f a)
       ) 
    => (a-> Bool) -> t a -> f a
filterF funct u= foldMap (\x -> if funct x then pure x else mempty) u
```

Mind you, I obviously don't understand this solution fully, as I can't figure out why those tests return `True`. What I do understand is this:

- `filterF` receives 2 arguments: `funct` (a function that takes an argument of type `a` and returns a Bool) and `u` (a foldable monoid)
- We let `funct` decide, for every element in `u`, if it should stay or not. If it does stay, we "raise" it up to the "rank" of an `Applicative` with `pure`
- we then combine all of the elements into one using the operation defined by the monoidal state of `f`

Given that in the tests we have the same LHS and different RHS, I would guess that the RHS influences the structure of `f`. A bit like how we would do in:

```
unit_testFilterF6=filterF Data.Char.isUpper"aNA aRe mEre" :: First Char
```

Can someone explain further what's going on here? I am a Haskell beginner.

Answer (score 1):

Let's write `f` for `(\x -> if funct x then pure x else mempty)`, when `funct` is `Data.Char.isUpper`.

We can evaluate `filterF Data.Char.isUpper "aNA aRe mEre"` as follows:

```
filterF Data.Char.isUpper "aNA aRe mEre"
= -- definition of filterF
folMap f "aNA aRe mEre"
= -- definition of foldMap
f 'a' <> f 'N' <> f 'A' <> f ' ' <> f 'a' <> f 'R' <> ....
= -- definition of f
mempty <> pure 'N' <> pure 'A' <> mempty <> mempty <> pure 'R' <> ...
= -- monoidal laws
pure 'N' <> pure 'A' <> pure 'R' <> pure 'E'
```

From here, using the definition of `<>` from the several monoids you mentioned, you should be able to conclude.